LWC - Input field marked as required shows an error despite having a value in it

I have two components, Parent and Child. The child component has a set of lightning-combobox and lightning-input fields. The default value for these are passed down from the parent after it computes these values.
I've written a simple validation on click of a button to validate the inputs in the child component by using checkValidity(). My input field shows an error even though the value is correctly passed down by the parent
The specific input field in my child component's HTML is
<lightning-input type={fieldValueType}
                        label='Value'
                        onchange={handleCheckedValueChange}
                        value={fieldValue}
                        step="0.01"
                        required={isFieldValueRequired}
                        lwc:ref="fieldValueInput">
 </lightning-input>

Here fieldValueType and fieldValue are @api properties and are passed down by the parent component correctly.I can verify that with the logs in my method that validates the inputs.
Method to validate the inputs
@api validateInputs() {
    return ([...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input,lightning-combobox')].reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
        if(!inputCmp.checkValidity()){
            console.group('Validity-Check');
            console.log('Check Validity : ', inputCmp.checkValidity());
            console.log('Mapping being checked : ', this.mapping);
            console.log('Field Value ', this.fieldValue);
            console.log('FieldValue Element : ', this.refs.fieldValueInput.value);
            console.groupEnd('Validity-Check');
        }
        inputCmp.reportValidity();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
    }, true));
}

The logs show me correct values here as I'd expect them to. However, the FieldValue Element log gives me an empty output
Log Output:
 Validity-Check
 Check Validity :  false
 Mapping being checked :  {requirementType: 'Object', requirementObject: 'Opportunity', requirementLevel: 'Hard', requirementField: 'Primary_Deployment_Cloud__c', operator: 'equals', …}
 Field Value  AWS
 FieldValue Element :  

The error doesn't go away until I actually modify the value in the input. What could be going on here ?

Here's at least one way to get into the described situation:

Set "fieldValueType" to "number"
Set "fieldValue" to "AWS"
Set "fieldValueType" to "text"

After the second step, the "AWS" will not appear in the field - it's not a number.
But after the third step, it will - the value was kept somewhere, apparently.
The result is that "fieldValue" is set to "AWS", but asking the element, it won't have a value, and therefore the validation fails.
This is just one scenario, I guess. You can open the DevTools of your Chrome (or whatever) and track what's going on in the "input" base component. You can find it under
components / lightning / input.js
and it has getters and setters for "type", "required" and "value".
Bottom line: One has to be careful with the order of setting the three attributes - make sure the "value" is technically set after the "type".

I couldn't figure out the actual root cause but following your advice, I added some random delays with Promise.resolve() and it started working just fine
